# Calculate $\sum^\infty _{k=1} \frac{10^{-k-1}}{k(k+1)}$ using the Taylor series of $(1-x)\ln(1-x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

For the Maclaurin series of $(1-x)\ln(1-x)$ I have obtained 
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k}$$
I am unsure on how to use this to obtain the value of the sum: $$ \sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{\left (\frac{1}{10} \right )^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|x|<1$, then
$$
(1-x)\ln(1-x)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k}
=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k}-\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}-x
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{10^{-k-1}}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{9}{10}\ln \Big(\frac{9}{10}\Big)
$$

Comment: why is there a $-x$ on the RHS of the last sum?

Comment: Because,  before the "=" the first sum starts from $k=1$ while the second starts from $k=0$, so there is an $-x$ more in the second sum.

Comment: What method would you suggest using to show that the sum then converges to $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{9}{10}\ln \Big(\frac{9}{10}\Big)$?

Comment: Ratio test works for this series.

Comment: Also root test.